# Topology Manage Error "CdTopologyType purposes should match CdEnvironments purposes"

Tags: web8, topology-manager

I am trying to create CDTopology for the below CDEnvironment & CDTopologyType

**CDEnvironment:**

```
EnvironmentPurpose   : DXALive
DiscoveryEndpointUrl : http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc
Credentials          : "AuthenticationType":"OAuth", "ClientId":"cmuser", "ClientSecret":"CMUserP@ssw0rd"
IsOffline            : False
ScopedRepositoryKeys : {}
Id                   : CDLive
ExtensionProperties  : {}
```

**CDTopologyType:**

```
Name                                          EnvironmentPurposes                          Id                                           ExtensionProperties                         
----                                          -------------------                          --                                           -------------------
SDL DXA Staging/Live                          {DXAStaging, DXALive}                        DXAStagingLive                               {}
```

Now, when I run the below command to create CDTopology, I am getting an error.

```
Add-TtmCdTopology -Id DXALive -CdTopologyTypeId DXAStagingLive -CdEnvironmentIds CDLive -Name "DXA Live" -Description "DXA Live"
```

Error:

```
Add-TtmCdTopology : Invalid value for property 'CdEnvironmentIds'. CdTopologyType purposes should match CdEnvironments purposes. CdTopologyType purposes: DXAStaging, CdEnvironments
 purposes: .
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-TtmCdTopology -Id DXALive -CdTopologyTypeId DXAStagingLive -CdEnvironmentIds ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Tridion.Topolog...TopologyCommand:AddCdTopologyCommand) [Add-TtmCdTopology], DataServiceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Tridion.TopologyManager.Automation.AddCdTopologyCommand
```

Can anyone please help?

Thanks 
Sharad

Answer (score 4):

Your Topology Type says there must be exactly two CD Environments in a Topology of that type: one with Purpose `DXAStaging` and one with Purpose `DXALive`.

Then you try to create a Topology of that type with only one CD Environment.

The error message is trying to tell you that you are violating your own Topology Type constraints.

**UPDATE**

Since you are using "DXA" in the names of your Purposes, it seems you are setting something up for DXA. Are you aware that DXA comes with a PowerShell script (`ttm-prepare.ps1`) that takes care of all of this for you?

Note that that script (and the predefined BPTs that come with DXA) assumes your CD Environments have `Staging` and (optionally) `Live` as Purpose, though.

Comment: Yes I do have two CD Environments, one with DXAStaging, and one with DXALive, with different Discovery URLs.

Comment: My point is that you must specify them **both** when creating a Topology of type `DXAStagingLive`.  Or, better, don't do this yourself, but use `ttm-prepare.ps1`.

Comment: indeed.. I am sure it would have beem fixed, but just for others..
Please have as many cdEnvironment as many Purposes you have in a particular TopologyType.